# Are there iOS API calls to get access to the UMTS pdp interface on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, pdp

I want to get some infos about the cellular network the UMTS interface on my iphone is connected to. Does anyone know API calls, that do this job. I remember an app on android os, where it was possible to get such info. I'm doing some Objective-C programming and was wondering if that'd be possible or if Apple does not support that.

Eventually I want to get something like this on the iphone, which is a super cool app!

http://www.panix.com/~mpoly/android/antennas/r1.0/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a public api for this. 
The only think that you can read is

```
  allowsVOIP  property
  carrierName  property
  isoCountryCode  property
  mobileCountryCode  property
  mobileNetworkCode  property
```

From [CTCarrier Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596)

Take a look to the [Core Telephony Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html)